# Which of the following compounds do not undego electrophilic aromatic substitution?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

Which of the following does not undergo electrophilic aromatic substitution?
[image]

Answer is option (D). But I am not able to understand why. All of them have lone pairs. I can notice only two differences. Functional group in Option (d) has the largest size and lowest electronegativity.

I think that may be because of a large difference in size of Selenium and Carbon, pie bond formation in between them will be a bit difficult, but that bond is not playing any role here except stabilizing the compound.

Low electronegativity seems like a good thing to me as it does not deactivates the compound.
So what am I missing here?

Comment: @AvatarShiny Couldn't you say the same for sulphur?

Comment: Se has bigger d orbitals. It's softer. @Gaurang

Comment: @AvatarShiny I still can't understand why will d- orbitals effect the reaction.

Comment: @AvatarShiny Oh so you're saying that it will be easier to take electrons from Se because of d orbitals? That must be it. Thank you.

Comment: @VJ Your thinking is correct.  Selenium is the largest atom of the series, it is in Period 4 while the others are in Periods 2 and 3.  It's larger size precludes effective overlap with the carbon pi orbitals.  Whereas molecules A-C are "aromatic" because the heteroatom lone pair is involved in overlap with the dienyl system to make a 6 pi electron ring, the selenium atom can't participate like this so molecule D is not "aromatic" like the others

Comment: @ron Oh. Thanks for helping. So conclusively, there is no aromaticity and no substitution either (according to Avatar Shiny) right?

Comment: @VJ  Yes, that is correct under normal reaction conditions.  Although I suspect that under "forcing" conditions, something will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenophene) disagrees.  Selenophene does undergo EAS, and apparently faster than thiophene.

*None* of the proposed answers to the original question is correct.